# How can I group by a part of timestamp value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I try to split and output the csv file. I must use the date to be the file name but don't need the time.
So I want to split the Order_Date, which is a timestamp that has both date and time.
How can I group by a part of value in pandas?
There is my code:

```
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',delimiter='|')

for i,x in df.groupby('Order_Date'):
    p = os.path.join(r'~/Desktop/',("data_{}.csv").format(i.lower()))
    x.to_csv(p,sep = '|', index=False)
```

Now I can get this:

```
data_2019-07-23 00:06:00.csv
data_2019-07-23 00:06:50.csv
data_2019-07-23 00:06:55.csv
data_2019-07-28 12:31:00.csv
```

Example test.csv data:

```
Channel|Store_ID|Store_Code|Store_Type|Order_ID|Order_Date|Member_ID|Member_Tier|Coupon_ID|Order_Total|Material_No|Material_Name|Size|Quantity|Unit_Price|Line_Total|Discount_Amount
ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|A190700|2019-07-23 00:06:00||||1064.00|7564|Full Zip|750|1.00|399.00|168.00|231.00
ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|A190700|2019-07-23 00:06:00||||1064.00|1361|COOL TEE|200|1.00|199.00|84.00|115.00
ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|A190700|2019-07-23 00:06:00||||1064.00|7699|PANT|690|1.00|499.00|210.00|289.00
ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|A190700|2019-07-23 00:06:00||||1064.00|8700|AI DRESS|690|1.00|399.00|196.00|203.00
ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|A190700|2019-07-23 00:06:50||||1064.00|8438|COPA|690|1.00|229.00|112.00|117.00
ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|A190700|2019-07-23 00:06:55||||1064.00|8324|CLASS|350|1.00|599.00|294.00|305.00
ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|ECOM|A190701|2019-07-28 12:31:00||||798.00|3689|DRESS|500|1.00|699.00|294.00|405.00
```

Expect I get this:

```
data_2019-07-23.csv
data_2019-07-28.csv
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `Order_Date` to dates - stripping the time information. One quick way to do this is:

`df['Order_Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order_Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Then proceed with a groupby using `Order_Date1`.

Comment: yes, this is the quick way to do this. Thank you. But if I don't want to add a new column, how can I do this?

Comment: The ``groupby`` function supports both column names and series. ``df.groupby('Order_Date')`` is the same as ``df.groupby(df['Order_Date'])``.So in this case, you can change the argument inside the ``groupby`` from ``'Order_Date'`` to ``pd.to_datetime(df['Order_Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')``, which is the column that would have been created.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the i a string and then using .split() and then using the 0 index:

`str(i).split()[0]`

so replaced in your code:

```
for i,x in df.groupby('Order_Date'):
    p = os.path.join(r'~/Desktop/',("data_{}.csv").format(str(i).split()[0]))
    x.to_csv(p,sep = '|', index=False)
```